# No subsequence converges when sequence has limit point in topological space

Tags: general-topology

In general topological space, suppose $x_0$ is a limit point of a sequence $\{x_n\}$, is it possible that there is no subsequence that converges to it？

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Let $X=\Bbb N$, with the topology generated by the base

$$\big\{\{n\}:n\ge 2\big\}\cup\big\{\{0,1\}\big\}\;,$$

and let $x_n=n$ for $n\in\Bbb N$. Then $\{x_n:n\in\Bbb N\}=X$, and every nbhd of $0$ contains $1$, a point of $X$ different from $0$, so $0$ is a limit point of the set $X$, but the sequence clearly has no subsequence converging to $0$ (or to anything else!).

> **Added:** This can easily be improved to a $T_0$ example. Again let $X=\Bbb N$, but for each $n\in\Bbb N$ let $V_n=\{k\in\Bbb N:k<n\}$, and let the topology be
>
> $$\{\Bbb N\}\cup\{V_n:n\in\Bbb N\}\;.$$
>
> The resulting space is easily seen to be $T_0$. Again consider the sequence $\sigma=\langle n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$. *Every* point of $X\setminus\{0\}$ is a limit point of the set $X$, since every nbhd of every point contains $0$, but no $V_n$ contains a tail of any subsequence of $\sigma$.

For a less trivial example, let $\mathscr{U}$ be a free ultrafilter on $\Bbb N$, and let $X=\{p\}\cup\Bbb N$. Points of $\Bbb N$ are isolated, and $U\subseteq X$ is an open nbhd of $p$ if and only if $p\in U$ and $U\cap\Bbb N\in\mathscr{U}$. Then $p$ is a limit point of the set $\Bbb N$, but no subsequence of $\langle n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ converges to $p$. To prove this, let $A\subseteq\Bbb N$, and consider the subsequence $\langle n:n\in A\rangle$. If $A\notin\mathscr{U}$, then $X\setminus A$ is a nbhd of $p$ disjoint from $A$. If $A\in\mathscr{U}$, split $A$ into complementary infinite subsets $A_0$ and $A_1$. Exactly one of them is in $\mathscr{U}$; without loss of generality let it be $A_0$. Then $\{p\}\cup A_1$ is a nbhd of $p$ that excludes infinitely many terms of $\langle n:n\in A\rangle$, so $\langle n:n\in A\rangle$ does not converge to $p$.

Comment: I'm confused by your argument. The following argument seems to work to prove the contrary: Let $\{a_n\}$ be a convergent sequence that converges to $x_0$. Then let $U$ be a neighborhood of $x_0$. Then there is some $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n \geq N$ implies that $a_n \in U$. Suppose that $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and $k \geq N$. Then $n_k \geq k \geq N$. Hence $a_{n_{k}} \in U$.

Comment: @Andres: As I read your question, it does not contain an assumption that the sequence $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ is convergent; it merely assumes that the $\{x_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ has a limit point. If you’re assuming that the sequence is convergent, the answer is completely trivial: the sequence is a convergent subsequence of itself.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott thanks a lot, the reason why I ask this question is because I want to understand why compactness doesn't imply sequentially compact. Obviously, when the space is compact, then  the sequence has a cluster point.

Comment: @89085731: I added that example so as to have a Hausdorff example. The first example isn’t even $T_0$, but it *is* an example, so you can ignore the second one for now. I just realized that I can improve the first one to make it $T_0$, though, so I’ll do that.

Comment: @89085731: Unfortunately, it’s the ultrafilter example that best explains why compactness doesn’t imply sequential compactness, since in that setting one is usually intererested in Hausdorff spaces. Informally, what makes it work is that the space is very strongly non-first-countable at $p$. What you really need to know about the ultrafilter $\mathscr{U}$ here is that it’s a family of infinite subsets of $\Bbb N$ with the (among others) the property that if $A\in\mathscr{U}$, $B\subseteq A$, and $C=A\setminus B$, then exactly one of $B$ and $C$ belongs to $\mathscr{U}$.

Comment: I see, thanks a lot

Comment: @89085731: You’re welcome.

Comment: Isnt this space (in added section) first countable? If so, the sequence must have a subsequence convergent to limit point of the sequence ? @BrianM.Scott

Comment: Or can you give an example a sequence $<x_{n}: n\in\mathbb{N}>$ such that the sequence has a limit point $x$  but there is no subsequence of it converging to $x$ @BrianM.Scott

Comment: @Woodx: That $X$ is second countable (and in fact has a countable topology), so it is certainly first countable.  In fact, for each $n\in\Bbb N$ the one-element set $\{V_{n+1}\}$ is a local base at $n$. This implies that if $A\subseteq X$, and $x$ is a limit point of the *set* $A$, then there is a sequence in $A$ converging to $x$. (In fact $x$ is a limit point of the set $A$ iff there is an $a\in A$ such that $a<x$, and in that case the constant sequence $\langle a,a,a\ldots\rangle$ converges to $x$.) We’re not talking about a convergent sequence: we’re talking about a sequence whose ...

Comment: ... underlying *set* of points has a limit point. See also the first comment above by Andres Mejia and my response to it.

Comment: I understood it now, thank you. But can we find a topological space in which  a sequence which has a limit point $x$ but no subsequence of the sequence converges to $x$? @BrianM.Scott

Comment: @Woodx: It is true in all spaces that if a sequence $\sigma$ converges to a point $x$, then every subsequence of $\sigma$ converges to $x$.

Comment: I am sorry, I meant accumulation point of sequence. Not limit point. So, can we find a sequence have an accumulation point $x$ but no subsequence of it converges to $x$. @BrianM.Scott

Comment: @Woodx: By definition a point is an accumulation point (or cluster point) of a sequence iff the sequence has a subsequence that converges to it. (There is some variation in terminology regarding these topics, and it’s possible that someone uses a different definition, but that’s the one that I consider standard.)

Comment: Okay, there was a theorem that one side of it is true just for the first countable spaces, a sequence has a cluster point, there need not be a subsequence of the sequence that converges to this point. Maybe the “cluster point” is a different one they mean in the theorem. @BrianM.Scott

Comment: @Woodx: Let $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ be a sequence in a topological space $X$. In my terminology they’re talking about a cluster point of the **set** $\{x_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$, which need not be a cluster point of the **sequence** $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$. The set is just a subset of $X$; the sequence is a function from $\Bbb N$ to $X$. And it is true that if $X$ is not first countable, it is possible for the set $\{x_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ to have a cluster point (accumulation point) in $X$ that is not a cluster point of the sequence $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$, meaning that ...

Comment: ... no subsequence of $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ converges to it.

Comment: So that’s why I required an example, that sequence (not the set) $<x_{n}:n\in\mathbb{N}>$ has a  (not the set) $x$, but the sequence has NO subsequence converging to $x$. @BrianM.Scott

Comment: @Woodx: If $\sigma=\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ has a cluster point $x$, then by my definition of *cluster point of a sequence* $\sigma$ necessarily has a subsequence converging to $x$. If instead you say that $x$ is a cluster point of $\sigma$ if $\{n\in\Bbb N:x_n\in V\}$ is infinite whenever $V$ is an open nbhd of $x$, then the last space in my answer gives you an example: $\langle n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ has $p$ as a cluster point but has no subsequence converging to $p$.

Comment: Thank you very much Brian, it’s settled. @BrianM.Scott

Comment: @Woodx: You’re very welcome.

Comment: Following the definition of *cluster point of a sequence* [in wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accumulation_point#sequence_accumulation_point), there may not exist a subsequence converging to the cluster point.  For an example, an enumeration of the points of the [Arens-Fort space](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000023) has the unique non-isolated point as a cluster point, but no subsequence converging to it.

Comment: (just to give some variety besides your ultrafilter example)